# Response time when sending post to Http GCM server is very high

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I am developing an application server to send GCM messages. My application server is sending post requests to GCM connection servers with HTTP protocol. The average response time of a request is acceptable (around 100 milliseconds), but sometimes I'm getting responses with times greater than 1 second. More occasionally I've got some response times of 2, 4 seconds or even more.
I'm using this library [gcm-server](https://github.com/google/gcm) to send my requests to GCM servers. I believe it's owned by Google. 
In order to despite the problem, I've made some analysis in the gcm-server library code but can't found any clue or answer. Ultimately, I decide to send some curl's with valid posts to GCM server. The results are the same. I'm sure this is not the expected behavior, maybe I'm doing something wrong, but can't find or understand what it is.

Below is the script I'm running to test this. I'm sending 1000 post requests to GCM, without any definition of Keep-Alive (by default cURL uses Keep-Alive enabled).

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..1000}; do

    curl -s -w "%{http_code} - %{time_total}\n" -o /dev/null -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: key={putHereOneGCMValidToken}}" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -d '{
      "collapse_key": "92667ba1-c8e9-4018-bf14-156417065641",
      "delay_while_idle": false,
      "data": {
        "field1": "value1",
        "field2": "value2"
      },
      "time_to_live": 0,
      "registration_ids": [
        "REGISTRATION_ID_1",
        "REGISTRATION_ID_2",
        "BAD_REGISTRATION_ID"
      ]
    }' "https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send";
    sleep 0.2;

done
```

Reference:

- [GCM http server documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref)

Answer (score 0):

You are queuing your server with too many Downstream Messaging. Try sending with a lower test numbers. If you are testing or sending to multiple devices or users try [Device Group Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/notifications) or [Send Messages to Topics](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/topic-messaging).

> Device Group Messaging
>
> - With device group messaging, app servers can send a single message to multiple instances of an app running on devices belonging to a group.
>
> Send Messages to Topics
>
> - GCM topic messaging allows your app server to send a message to multiple devices that have opted in to a particular topic.

Also, you must consider external factor like intermittent internet connection for the delay of receiving the message. Lastly you might want to check this related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35095054/5995040) that experience High Server CPU after sending GCM.

Hope this helps!

Comment: In my application server I'm already grouping messages, I'm sending a single request to multiple registrationIds; even the test script has multiple registrationIds, to get a scenario closer to my reality. 
The propose of this test is to get samples to help me understand the problems I'm facing. In my application server, I'm not sending 1000 requests sequentially, that is for sure; I'm sending a great quantity of requests to GCM but they are not sequentially, and sometimes I get some  high response times, like I had reported.

Thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: I have changed my test script to send only 10 requests and sleep for 2 seconds between each 10 requests run. In only 5 runs I got a response with 3.074 and another with 1.347.